# Merge rows with the same primary key and calculate average for new value

Tags: c#, mysql, database, postgresql, merge

I have a table which looks like the following: 
[image]

As you can see in the image above, the primary key consists of the intervalstart and the edgeid. What I am trying to do now is to import records with the same intervalstart and the same edgeid, BUT with different values for avgvelocity, measurementcount and vehiclecount.
But as I want to avoid duplicate entries in the table, I want to merge those records with a duplicate key and calculate the average value over the avgvelocity, measurementcount and vehiclecount columns.

I have already found the PostgreSQL command called MERGE but I cannot get my head around on how to do this. 
Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be looking at the [MySQL GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) or [PostgresSQL GROUP BY](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_group_by.htm) clause to do what you want.

```
SELECT intervalstart,edgeid, AVG(avgvelocity), AVG(measurementcount), AVG(vehiclecount) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY intervalstart, edgeid
```

All records are grouped ("merged") by intervalstart and edgeid, you can then use aggregate functions such as AVG for average on the non-grouped columns.

In MySQL (I don't know about PostgresSQL) - if you want the "day" column - you can get that using the ANY_VALUE function, that will get a value from one of the rows.

```
SELECT intervalstart,edgeid, ANY_VALUE(day), AVG(avgvelocity), AVG(measurementcount), AVG(vehiclecount) 
FROM mytable GROUP BY intervalstart, edgeid
```